# Sublime Text3: LaTeX Tools with Custom Command not working correctly

Tags: build, latex, sublimetext3, move, sublime-text-plugin

I needed to customize the settings from LaTeX tools, so that the glossaries package works.

Now everything works fine. But I also want to have the temporary files in one folder and the produced PDF at the .tex file.

The first thing works fine: Everything is in the build folder. But I can't get the PDF File out of this folder because my quotes will be deleted in the script commands.

Here are my script commands for building:

```
"script_commands": [
  "latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -auxdir=build -outdir=build",
  "makeglossaries -d build",
  "latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -auxdir=build -outdir=build",
  "move /y \"build/$file_base_name.pdf\" \"$file_base_name.pdf\"",
  "move /y \"build/$file_base_name.synctex.gz\" \"$file_base_name.synctex.gz\"",
  // "move /y \"build/$file_base_name.log\" \"$file_base_name.log\""
]
```

The first three commands works fine. The PDF gets correctly build. But the move command does not work.
I've also tried to use the full path but the problem was that I can't do a  `\` sign so that the call looked like `move /y C:\path\to\the\texdocument/build/Document.pdf` which also not worked.
I've also tried to use the `'` signs. And copy as a replacement for move. But doesn't help.

Can someone help me?

P.S.: I'm using Windows.

// **Edit**: I've also a question regarding the Logoutput: Is it possible to show Errors and Warning via LaTeX Tools? Like the built in builders?

This is now the script-building system.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is, that LaTeXTools calls the script builder command with `shell` set to `False`. Hence the `move` command is not available. Do you use cygwin or have Coreutils available? Can you open the cmd and write `where mv`?

Comment: @r-stein Thanks for your answer. I've installed coreutils now. `where mv` directs me now to `C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin\mv.exe`.  But how can I now enable `shell` so that is true. Or better how can I make it work now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script does not work, because LaTeXTools sets `shell` to `False` when calling the build command. Hence you can only call programs and not shell commands like `move`. If you have Cygwin or Coreutils installed they ship the `mv` program, which is the unix move command. It is installed as a program rather than a command and can be used in the builder.

Just change your build to:

```js
"script_commands": [
  "latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -auxdir=build -outdir=build",
  "makeglossaries -d build",
  "latexmk -cd -e -f -pdf -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  -auxdir=build -outdir=build",
  "mv -f \"build\\$file_base_name.pdf\" \"$file_base_name.pdf\"",
  "mv -f \"build\\$file_base_name.synctex.gz\" \"$file_base_name.synctex.gz\"",
  "mv -f \"build\\$file_base_name.log\" \"$file_base_name.log\""
]
```

To answer your additional question:
If you have the log file available it will automatically parse and show errors and warnings.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But It also says everytime `COULD NOT COMPILE!`. The command it invokes is `Invoking 'mv -f 'build\Thesis.pdf' Thesis.pdf'...`. Everything looks fine: File is build. But the copy command does not work. I've copied the Command and it seems to be again the `'`sign which is the Problem. I've tried without, with a `/` instead of an `\` but didn't work. Have you an Idea?

Comment: @CodeRain weird that works for me. Could you set the setting `display_log` inside `builder_settings` to `true`? This shows the shell output of each command in the output panel and should give a hint about the problem.

Comment: Thats now really strange. I copied exactly your commands. It didnt worked. I enabled the log... It worked. What is this...? Strange. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @CodeRain glad to help. Since LaTeXTools does exactly the same except from writing the output, I would assume there is an other reason. This could be closing and opening Sublime Text, such that the environment variables are updated.